# Access attribute of template base class without "using"

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I want to use an attribute defined in the template base class `A` in a method of template derived class `B`.
So far, I found `using` works.
But writing a `using` statement for every single attribute of `A` is tedious.
How to avoid writing so many `using` statements?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class A{
    public:
        A(){
            a = 10;
        }
        //virtual destructor
        virtual ~A(){
            cout << "~A() is called" << endl;
        }
    protected:
        T a;
} ;

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T>{
    public:
        void f(void){
            cout << a << endl;
        }
        virtual ~B(){
            cout << "~B() is called" << endl;
        }
    private:
        using A<T>::a; //how to get rid of this?
} ;

int main(void){
    B<int> bb;
    bb.f();
}
```

Comment: Check out [this macro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56326061/8769985)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are extending a class that is dependent of a template parameter, `this` become a dependent name. You must use `this` explicitly:

```
template <typename T>
struct B : A<T>{
    void f(){
        std::cout << this->a << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Or you can even specify the class name:

```
template <typename T>
struct B : A<T>{
    void f(){
        std::cout << A<T>::a << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The third solution is, of course, the `using` statement.

Comment: *"//how to get rid of this [using]?"*: by **using** `this` ^_^

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // how to get rid of this?
> ```

You can write

```
    void f(void){
        cout << A<T>::a << endl;
    }
```

or

```
    void f(void){
        cout << this->a << endl;
    }
```

to get rid of the `using` statement.